# Android general pattern for intercepting session error, handling error with screen, continue at same point before the error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, error-handling, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a productive Android application using Activities, Fragments and IntentServices. New requirements force me to integrate a monitoring/tracking backend, to track actions the user executes in the app. To simplify the problem image that every button .setOnClickListener() should execute an HTTP backend call first, before continue with the business logic. I integrated the monitoring REST backend using swagger in combination with okhttp v.2.7 which I call from an async task. First step in the application is now a login screen that calls login() on the backend i.e. creates a HTTP session and persists a secure session token returned by the backend. Every call to the backend automatically injects a HTTP header with the secure session token.
I am also using OkHTTP interception listeners for logging requests to Android logcat.
It seems that this approach is working fine but I have an issue with secure token expiration. After approximately one week the session with the backend expires and the Android application would need to initiate HTTP login() and store the new secure session token. Please note that the  backend is not under my control (token renewal in the backend won't work).
So far I can handle sudden session errors (HTTP Code 403 is returned by the backend) by investigating the OkHTTP ApiException, finishing the activity with a specific result code, handling the result code in the main activity by navigating to the login activity (of course the user himself has to navigate back to the screen he used before the error occured).

But this approach needs much code for every possible case depending on the calling entity. As I said in the beginning, I am using activities, fragments and intent services and every single entity has to call the backend for monitoring/tracking. So the error handling needs to be specifically tailored for every entity e.g. fragments need to tell the parent activity to raise and error. Having the error in the intent service is of course a harder issue.
(Android JetPack conditional navigation seems to be overkill for this case to me.)

I am wondering if there is a nice general pattern for this case, where the async task encapsulating tracking in the backend, can detect the error, show the login screen, then after successful login continue afterwards with the task.
More generally I would like to know, how to intercept an exception, pause the currently shown screen (activity or fragment), show a dedicated error solving screen, then resume on the previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first attempt, per Fragment / Activity the onPostExecute() methods needs to be implemented to handle the specific error case. The solution lacks a mechanism to continue execution exactly one line after navigateToLoginScreenToRenewSession() once the session is renewed, that's the hard part. I am wondering if anybody has a good solution for that.

```
public abstract class AbstractAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    public boolean isSessionError() {
    // instanceOf for HTTP exception and check for contained HTTP error code
    }

    protected void storeException(Exception e){
    }
}

public class ActuallyDoSomethingTask extends AbstractAsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
     try{
         // do something
     } catch(Exception e){
         storeException(e);
     }
}

public class SomeActivityUsingHttpSession extends Activity {

    private void onClickListener(){
       new ActuallyDoSomethingTask(){
           // specific implementation for activity / fragment case

           protected void onPostExecute(Void voids){
               if(isSessionError){
                   displayToastWithSessionErrorDescription();
                   navigateToLoginScreenToRenewSession();
                   // TODO continue execution after login screen successfully completed, how can we do that easily without huge boiler plate?
               }
           }
       }.execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas or comments for improvement?